iDRAC 9 (14th gen) Server Config Profiles via USB?
I'm trying to get Server Config Profiles working on a Dell R750 via the front Micro-USB port, but I'm having trouble getting the iDRAC to actually see the config files on the USB.
According to the documentation, a directory named System_Configuration_XML must exist in the USB root, and then two files (control.xml and config.xml, or maybe configuration.xml) need to be placed within that directory: control.xml specifies the config apply settings (reboot type, timeout, etc), while config.xml specifies the server settings (iDRAC/BIOS/RAID settings).
There is no mention in any documentation I could find on the specific filesystem to use.
I have tried NTFS, FAT32, exFAT and EXT2 filesystems, with the following file structure on each, with no luck. The log entry I've seen is similar to "the config file cannot be found, or there are multiple compressed files". I assume this means that the iDRAC cannot find the files, because I am not compressing anything.
|USB_ROOT
|-config.xml  
|-configuration.xml  
|-control.xml  
|-|System_Configuration_XML
|-|- config.xml
|-|- configuration.xml
|-|- control.xml

Has anyone actually managed to get the USB-based SCP configuration working for the 14th-gen servers?

Sources like this all suggest the same "The device has to be formatted as FAT32 to be recognized by the LifeCycle Controller to use USB as a source."  - N o idea why that isn't working for you though

Ah. I was only looking at SCP documentation, which doesn't ever mention the filesystem type. But it turns out there's a partition size requirement as well; 28GB doesn't work but 1GB does.

I found out the issue. Turns out the iDRAC doesn't like 28GB partitions. I created a 1GB partition formatted as FAT32 and it just worked.
